# Get rows from table of last 5 days in IBM DB2 by joining another table

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables in DB2.

```
table1
----
sidpk                 pid
--------------------------
24gsr3               xyz
67sfr9               xyz
67sts8               xyz

table2
-------------------------
sid                 date
--------------------------
24gsr3              2017-09-24
67sfr9              2017-09-23
67sts8              2017-09-15
.
.
and so on
```

I'm trying to fetch all rows that are available that were created 5 days before from today from table2.

In the above case, I expect it should return be 24gsr3, 67sfr9

What is missing in my query?

Please find it.

```
SELECT a.sidpk from table1 a
LEFT JOIN
table2 b
ON a.sidpk= b.sid
WHERE a.pid='xyz' AND b.date>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND 
b.date<= CURDATE()
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

Comment: Which OS? Do you get all rows or an error? Try current date - 5 days instead of date_sub

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, I'm using Microsoft. But how does it matter with OS?

Comment: Why don't you just use INNER JOIN ? I don't think that you are using LEFT JOIN on purpose.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas, Can you just try it execute that query?

Comment: @Aliy Db2 is available on multiple platforms with slightly differnt SQL functions. That is why the OS is important. DATE_SUB is not part of the functionality provided by Db2 (for Linux, Unix and Windows)

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, I'm using Microsoft OS for this. can you tell me the solution of this?

Comment: @Aliy I did in my first comment already:  Try current date - 5 days instead of date_sub

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, I tried as Rams update. But the TRUNCATE function is not accepting the parameters.. Number of arguments for function TRUNCATE not valid. [SQL State=42605, DB Errorcode=-170]

Comment: @Aliy I did not write anything about truncate - did I? You do not need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155178/discussion-between-aliy-and-michaeltiefenbacher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT a.sidpk from table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.sidpk= b.sid
 WHERE a.pid='xyz' 
   AND b.date >= current date - 5 days
   AND b.date <= current date
 ORDER BY b.date DESC
```